# Как имитировать переход на страницу из этой же страницы AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация

Доброго времени суток господа, У меня есть простое *CRUD* приложение, с возможностью добавления *Категорий* и *Телефонов* . Я разделил страницу надвое, слева находится *dx-treeview*(далее: дерево), справа - динамическое содержание, т.е. отображаются либо все телефоны категории, либо детали одного телефона, выбранного в *дереве*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, Datasource у *дерева* и *таблицей с телефонами* разные и находятся в двух разных контроллерах, за изменениями в дереве следит *$watch* и обновляет *datasource*, а правая часть страницы изменяется каждый раз при изменении адреса, вот мои настройки роутинга:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/HomePartial.html",
    controller: "defaultCtrl"
})
.when('/phone/:phoneId', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/PhoneDetails.html",
    controller: "phoneDetailsCtrl"
}).when('/category/:categoryId', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/Category.html",
    controller: "categoryCtrl"
});
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);
```

Все хорошо работает, только не с *"Изменением"* элементов:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменения вступают в силу справа  только после нажатия на какой-нибудь другой элемент на дереве.
Вот мой исходник моего локального хранилища выбранного эелемена в дереве:

```
myApp.controller('phoneDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, phonesAndCategoriesStorages, $routeParams) {
phonesFromFile = [];
phonesAndCategoriesStorages.getPhonesFromServer().then(function (response) {
    phonesFromFile = response;
}).then(function () {
    $scope.localStorragePhone = [phonesAndCategoriesStorages.getPhone($routeParams.phoneId, phonesFromFile)];
});


});
```

я пробовал использовать, сразу после сохранения изменений, редеректить с помощью *$location.path(..)*, *window.location(..)*, *window.location.href = ...* *window.location.replace* ..., помогает только *window.reload*, но это не то, мне не нужна полная перезагрузка страницы. Может кто-нибудь подскажет еще какой-нибудь способ, чтобы обновить страницу ?
Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: добавьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не нужны релоады-они действительно перезапустят.
установите html5 mode и меняйте ссылку по ng-link. посмотрите в гугле примеры в эту сторону